# How to use GLSLshader::operator[]

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been reading through a book on OpenGL that says you can use the GLSLshader::operator[] with the name of the attribute I want the location for to get that location. However when I use it (example below) the program crashes.

```
GLuint program_id;
...
glLinkProgram(program_id);
...
...
...
glEnableVertexAttribArray(program_id["position");
glVertexAttribPointer(program_id["position"], ... );
```

When I debug it returns 105 even though I expect it to return 0. I have specified that the location should be 0 and when I hard code it it works as expected:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ... );
```

This is the line from the vertex shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
```

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood how to use this. Up until now I've always hard coded the attribute locations, but I'd like to be able to do it this way. I know I can also use

```
glGetAttribLocation(program_id, "position");
```

and that works (it returns the location I specify) but shader["position"] looks clearer to me and if using the [] operator is one way to do it I'd like to know how to do it rather that just finding a work around to make it work.

So my question is can you use the GLSLshader::operator[] such as shader["position"] to get the location of an attribute? If so can you think of what I might be doing that are making it not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear about this, it was asked and answered correctly in about 2 minutes. I was unsure about how to use the GLSLshader::operator[] and asked for clarification, and Martijn Courteaux understood the question and answered that GLSLshader would have been a class created by the book I was using and not the OpenGL program object as I originally thought. Anyway I have the answer now so I don't require any more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GLSLshader will be a class that is defined in the book you are reading. There will be an operator[] defined. This GLSLshader class is not default (also because OpenGL is actually a C library where classes do not exist).

FYI: `GLuint` is just a typedef to a fixed 32 bit unsigned number. (Eg in C++: `uint32_t`)

Comment: Not necessarily; `GLuint` is ***required*** to be 32-bit. "`unsigned integer`" does not imply anything about size. Where applicable it might be `typedef unsigned int GLuint` but for portability, do not ever assume that.

Comment: Actually `GLuint` is not *just* a typedef to `unsigned int`. The OpenGL specification explicitly states which size a `GLuint` is, in particular a `GLuint` always is 32 bits, even on systems on which a regular `unsigned int` would be just 16 bits, or maybe even 64 bits. `GLuint` is independent of this.

Comment: Oh, thanks guys! I didn't know that `int` was variable in size depending on the platform. Will update the answer! :D